# How to translate Lambda expression in C# to C++

Tags: c#, c++, function, lambda

I'm woking on MinHash function.I just found some code in C# but I want to write in C++ due to my exist code are in C++.

I'm quite confused about lambda expression and delegate function.

The C# codes is like

```
public delegate uint Hash(int toHash);
private Hash[] hashFunctions;

// Public access to hash functions
public Hash[] HashFunctions
{
    get { return hashFunctions; }
}

// Generates the Universal Random Hash functions
// http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_hashing
private void GenerateHashFunctions(int u)
{
    hashFunctions = new Hash[numHashFunctions];

    // will get the same hash functions each time since the same random number seed is used
    Random r = new Random(10);
    for (int i = 0; i < numHashFunctions; i++)
    {
        uint a = 0;
        // parameter a is an odd positive
        while (a % 1 == 1 || a <= 0)
            a = (uint)r.Next();
        uint b = 0;
        int maxb = 1 << u;
        // parameter b must be greater than zero and less than universe size
        while (b <= 0)
            b = (uint)r.Next(maxb);
        hashFunctions[i] = x => QHash(x, a, b, u);
    }
}
// Universal hash function with two parameters a and b, and universe size in bits
private static uint QHash(int x, uint a, uint b, int u)
{
    return (a * (uint)x + b) >> (32 - u);
}
```

I've tried to translate into C++ by create struct but I still don't know what to do with this line

```
hashFunctions[i] = x => QHash(x, a, b, u);
```

C++ code I've got till now

```
 struct Hash
    {
    // Universal hash function with two parameters a and b, and universe size in   bits
    unsigned int operator()(int toHash)      
        {     

    }
};


    Hash* hashFunctions;

    void GenerateHashFunctions(int u)
        {
            hashFunctions = new Hash[numHashFunction];

            // will get the same hash functions each time since the same random number seed is used
                for (int i = 0; i < numHashFunction; i++)
            {
                    unsigned int a = 0;
                    // parameter a is an odd positive
                    while (a % 1 == 1 || a <= 0)
                        a = (unsigned int)rand()%10;
                    unsigned int b = 0;
                    int maxb = 1 << u;
                    // parameter b must be greater than zero and less than universe size
                    while (b <= 0)
                        b = (unsigned int)rand()%maxb;;

            //hashFunctions[i] = x => QHash(x, a, b, u);
            }
    }

    static unsigned QHash(int x,unsigned int a,unsigned int b,int u) 
    {
        return (a * (unsigned int)x + b) >> (32 - u);
    }
```

Anyone please give me some advise? Thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

Use a C++ lambda expression.

```
hashFunctions[i] = [=] (auto x) { return QHash(x, a, b, u); };
```

Also please avoid using raw pointers or arrays.
Use a standard container such as

```
std::vector<std::function<uint (int)>>
```

Furthermore, you should not use c style casts such as

```c++
(unsigned)(expression)
```

prefer

```
static_cast<unsigned>(expression)
```

Edit: Here is an example:

```c++
#include <vector>
#include <functional>

....

private:
using HashProvider = std::function<uint, (int)>;
auto GenerateHashFunctions(int u)
{
     auto hashFunctions = std::vector<HashProvider>(numHashFunctions);
     for (int i = 0; i < numHashFunctions; i++)
     {
        uint a = 0;
        // parameter a is an odd positive
        while (a % 1 == 1 || a <= 0) {
            a = static_cast<uint>(r.Next());
        }
        uint b = 0;
        int maxb = 1 << u;
        // parameter b must be greater than zero and less than universe size
        while (b <= 0) {
            b = static_cast<uint>(r.Next(maxb));
        }
        hashFunctions.push_back([=](auto x) { return QHash(x, a, b, u); });

   }
   return hashFunctions;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I will test it.

Comment: minHash.cpp: In member function ‘void MinHash::GenerateHashFunctions(int)’:
minHash.cpp:51:21: error: no match for ‘operator=’ (operand types are ‘MinHash::Hash’ and ‘MinHash::GenerateHashFunctions(int)::<lambda(auto:1)>’)
    hashFunctions[i] = [=] (auto x) { return QHash(x, a, b, u); };         }
                     ^
minHash.cpp:17:8: note: candidate: MinHash::Hash& MinHash::Hash::operator=(const MinHash::Hash&)
 struct Hash
        ^

Comment: What compiler are you using? Also note that you will need to change the element type of hashFunctions.

Comment: g++ version 5.2.0.

I didn't change any think but add lambda expression line yet.

Dose it effect the lambda expression?

Comment: Using the ```std::function``` type from the functional header is what I recommend. Then get rid of the Hash type entirely.

Comment: It's done complied. Thank you a lot. I really appreciated.

Comment: your example has a C cast